# Keyboard Error in bootup

Tags: boot, 16.04, keyboard, ssh, reboot

I recently installed a fresh version of 16.04 on a low to mid range desktop (HP Slimline) to use as a headless Plex server for some direct streaming. After a successful install, the plan was to stow the desktop away in a closet to run headless with just an ethernet connection and power. Management would be done via ssh from a remote computer on the network.

When I remove all the peripherals like the monitor, mouse and keyboard, and restart the system, the desktop refuses to reboot up and displays the message "Keyboard Error". I then need to plug in the keyboard and the system restarts just fine.

My question is, how can I run the desktop headless, with no keyboard? I looked in menu's and cant seem to find a solution. Would I need to switch operating systems to ubuntu server for better results?

Answer (score 0):

Hi for your use case I would recommend you by starting with the `ubuntu-server-image`, it even asks you on installation what services you want installed, like `sshd`.
This image mainly differs from the desktop-images by it's install routine and that it does not ship with an DesktopEnvironment (e.g. unity).
And after installation it can be run completely headless and without the need of an attached keyboard.